# Top open source single sign on app

Tags: single-sign-on, opensso, open-source

We're using a webapps like google apps(mail), jira, etc. and would like to implement single sign on on our system. What is the best or top pick when choosing a single sign on app? 
Is CAS(http://www.jasig.org/cas) a good choice?
BTW most of our machines are Ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Comment: curious your thoughts @Jonar on http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/21958/why-a-proposal-for-identity-access-management-makes-sense

Answer (score 1):

Give a try on following link http://www.josso.org/

http://cosign.sourceforge.net/

:)

Answer (score 1):

I've used [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) in the past and found it to be excellent for medium sized organisations (<500 employees). It integrates well with Java applications ([through Spring Security](http://jk-blogging.blogspot.com/2008/09/step-by-step-tutorial-on-cas-part1.html)) and is a very lightweight solution.

An alternative for a much, much bigger approach is [OpenSSO developed by Sun](http://wikis.sun.com/display/OpenSSO/getstarted). This is a total beast, but meets every conceivable requirement for an SSO policy.